# Why does Spark's GaussianMixture return identical clusters?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-analysis, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using spark-1.5.2 to cluster a dataset using `GaussianMixture`. No errors occur other than the resulting `GaussianMixtureModel`s and their weights are identical. The number of iterations it takes to reach the specified tolerance is about 2 which seems far too low.

What parameters can I adjust so that clusters form with different values?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.GaussianMixture
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

def sparkContext: SparkContext = {
  import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
  new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("console"))
}

implicit val sc = sparkContext

def observationsRdd(implicit sc: SparkContext): RDD[Vector] = {
  sc.textFile("observations.csv")
    .map { line => Vectors.dense(line.split(",").map { _.toDouble }) }
}

val gmm = {new GaussianMixture()
  .setK(6)
  .setMaxIterations(1000)
  .setConvergenceTol(0.001)
  .setSeed(1)
  .run(observationsRdd)}

for (i <- 0 until gmm.k) {
  println("weight=%f\nmu=%s\nsigma=\n%s\n" format
    (gmm.weights(i), gmm.gaussians(i).mu, gmm.gaussians(i).sigma))
}
```

Truncated output:

```
weight=0.166667
mu=[4730.358845338535,4391.695550847029,4072.3224046605947,4253.183898304653,4454.124682202946,4775.553442796136,4980.3952860164545,4812.717637711368,5120.44449152493,2820.1827330505857,180.10291313557565,4189.185858050445,3690.793644067457]
sigma=
422700.24745093845  382225.3248240414   398121.9356855869   ... (13 total)
382225.3248240414   471186.33178427175  455777.0565262309   ...
398121.9356855869   455777.0565262309   461210.0532084378   ...
469361.3787142044   497432.39963363775  515341.1303306988   ...
474369.6318494179   482754.83801426284  500047.5114985542   ...
453832.62301188655  443147.58931290614  461017.7038258409   ...
458641.51202210854  433511.1974652861   452015.6655154465   ...
387980.29836054996  459673.3283909025   455118.78272128507  ...
461724.87201332086  423688.91832506843  442649.18455604656  ...
291940.48273324646  257309.1054220978   269116.23674394307  ...
16289.3063964479    14790.06803739929   15387.484828872432  ...
334045.5231910066   338403.3492767321   350531.7768916226   ...
280036.0894114749   267624.69326772855  279651.401859903    ...

weight=0.166667
mu=[4730.358845338535,4391.695550847029,4072.3224046605947,4253.183898304653,4454.124682202946,4775.553442796136,4980.3952860164545,4812.717637711368,5120.44449152493,2820.1827330505857,180.10291313557565,4189.185858050445,3690.793644067457]
sigma=
422700.24745093845  382225.3248240414   398121.9356855869   ... (13 total)
382225.3248240414   471186.33178427175  455777.0565262309   ...
398121.9356855869   455777.0565262309   461210.0532084378   ...
469361.3787142044   497432.39963363775  515341.1303306988   ...
474369.6318494179   482754.83801426284  500047.5114985542   ...
453832.62301188655  443147.58931290614  461017.7038258409   ...
458641.51202210854  433511.1974652861   452015.6655154465   ...
387980.29836054996  459673.3283909025   455118.78272128507  ...
461724.87201332086  423688.91832506843  442649.18455604656  ...
291940.48273324646  257309.1054220978   269116.23674394307  ...
16289.3063964479    14790.06803739929   15387.484828872432  ...
334045.5231910066   338403.3492767321   350531.7768916226   ...
280036.0894114749   267624.69326772855  279651.401859903    ...

weight=0.166667
mu=[4730.358845338535,4391.695550847029,4072.3224046605947,4253.183898304653,4454.124682202946,4775.553442796136,4980.3952860164545,4812.717637711368,5120.44449152493,2820.1827330505857,180.10291313557565,4189.185858050445,3690.793644067457]
sigma=
422700.24745093845  382225.3248240414   398121.9356855869   ... (13 total)
382225.3248240414   471186.33178427175  455777.0565262309   ...
398121.9356855869   455777.0565262309   461210.0532084378   ...
469361.3787142044   497432.39963363775  515341.1303306988   ...
474369.6318494179   482754.83801426284  500047.5114985542   ...
453832.62301188655  443147.58931290614  461017.7038258409   ...
458641.51202210854  433511.1974652861   452015.6655154465   ...
387980.29836054996  459673.3283909025   455118.78272128507  ...
461724.87201332086  423688.91832506843  442649.18455604656  ...
291940.48273324646  257309.1054220978   269116.23674394307  ...
16289.3063964479    14790.06803739929   15387.484828872432  ...
334045.5231910066   338403.3492767321   350531.7768916226   ...
280036.0894114749   267624.69326772855  279651.401859903    ...

weight=0.166667
mu=[4730.358845338535,4391.695550847029,4072.3224046605947,4253.183898304653,4454.124682202946,4775.553442796136,4980.3952860164545,4812.717637711368,5120.44449152493,2820.1827330505857,180.10291313557565,4189.185858050445,3690.793644067457]
sigma=
422700.24745093845  382225.3248240414   398121.9356855869   ... (13 total)
382225.3248240414   471186.33178427175  455777.0565262309   ...
398121.9356855869   455777.0565262309   461210.0532084378   ...
469361.3787142044   497432.39963363775  515341.1303306988   ...
474369.6318494179   482754.83801426284  500047.5114985542   ...
453832.62301188655  443147.58931290614  461017.7038258409   ...
458641.51202210854  433511.1974652861   452015.6655154465   ...
387980.29836054996  459673.3283909025   455118.78272128507  ...
461724.87201332086  423688.91832506843  442649.18455604656  ...
291940.48273324646  257309.1054220978   269116.23674394307  ...
16289.3063964479    14790.06803739929   15387.484828872432  ...
334045.5231910066   338403.3492767321   350531.7768916226   ...
280036.0894114749   267624.69326772855  279651.401859903    ...

weight=0.166667
mu=[4730.358845338535,4391.695550847029,4072.3224046605947,4253.183898304653,4454.124682202946,4775.553442796136,4980.3952860164545,4812.717637711368,5120.44449152493,2820.1827330505857,180.10291313557565,4189.185858050445,3690.793644067457]
sigma=
422700.24745093845  382225.3248240414   398121.9356855869   ... (13 total)
382225.3248240414   471186.33178427175  455777.0565262309   ...
398121.9356855869   455777.0565262309   461210.0532084378   ...
469361.3787142044   497432.39963363775  515341.1303306988   ...
474369.6318494179   482754.83801426284  500047.5114985542   ...
453832.62301188655  443147.58931290614  461017.7038258409   ...
458641.51202210854  433511.1974652861   452015.6655154465   ...
387980.29836054996  459673.3283909025   455118.78272128507  ...
461724.87201332086  423688.91832506843  442649.18455604656  ...
291940.48273324646  257309.1054220978   269116.23674394307  ...
16289.3063964479    14790.06803739929   15387.484828872432  ...
334045.5231910066   338403.3492767321   350531.7768916226   ...
280036.0894114749   267624.69326772855  279651.401859903    ...

weight=0.166667
mu=[4730.358845338535,4391.695550847029,4072.3224046605947,4253.183898304653,4454.124682202946,4775.553442796136,4980.3952860164545,4812.717637711368,5120.44449152493,2820.1827330505857,180.10291313557565,4189.185858050445,3690.793644067457]
sigma=
422700.24745093845  382225.3248240414   398121.9356855869   ... (13 total)
382225.3248240414   471186.33178427175  455777.0565262309   ...
398121.9356855869   455777.0565262309   461210.0532084378   ...
469361.3787142044   497432.39963363775  515341.1303306988   ...
474369.6318494179   482754.83801426284  500047.5114985542   ...
453832.62301188655  443147.58931290614  461017.7038258409   ...
458641.51202210854  433511.1974652861   452015.6655154465   ...
387980.29836054996  459673.3283909025   455118.78272128507  ...
461724.87201332086  423688.91832506843  442649.18455604656  ...
291940.48273324646  257309.1054220978   269116.23674394307  ...
16289.3063964479    14790.06803739929   15387.484828872432  ...
334045.5231910066   338403.3492767321   350531.7768916226   ...
280036.0894114749   267624.69326772855  279651.401859903    ...
```

...

Additionally, the code, input data, and output data is available as a gist @ https://gist.github.com/aaron-santos/91b4931a446c460e082b2b3055b9950f

Thank you

Comment: Did you try changing the convergence tolerance ? It maybe got stuck in a local maximum. Try also to change seeds. I don't have a cluster now to test this.

Comment: Have you tried *other tools* such as ELKI and Weka? Clustering is not a particular strength of Spark. Also, does your data have many duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your data through ELKI (I had to remove the last line, which is incomplete). It at first did not work either, which I assume is due to the *scale* of the attributes, along with the default initialization. Probably the same problem is present in Spark.

After scaling the data, I could get some reasonable clusters with ELKI (visualizing the first three of 13 dimensions):

[image]

But judging from the distribution of the data points **I do not think Gaussian Mixture Modeling is appropriate for this data**. The points appear to be grid-sampled from some hypersurface or some trajectories; not from Gaussian (!) distributions.

Here are the ELKI parameters I used:

```
-dbc.in /tmp/observations.csv
-dbc.filter normalization.columnwise.AttributeWiseVarianceNormalization
-algorithm clustering.em.EM -em.k 6
-em.centers RandomlyChosenInitialMeans -kmeans.seed 0
```

It may be worth experimenting with other clustering algorithms such as HDBSCAN, which can identify density-based clusters:

[image]

Parameters:

```
-dbc.in /tmp/observations.csv
-dbc.filter normalization.columnwise.AttributeWiseVarianceNormalization
-algorithm clustering.hierarchical.extraction.HDBSCANHierarchyExtraction
-algorithm SLINKHDBSCANLinearMemory
-hdbscan.minPts 50 -hdbscan.minclsize 100
```

I would also try OPTICS, as I find HDBSCAN to often only capture the core of a cluster (by design). From the OPTICS plot, I would not say the clusters are very clearly defined.

Apart from trying other clustering algorithms, I think you also need to work a lot on preprocessing and projecting your data, because it has very strong correlations. Try to put as much prior knowledge on the data into your preprocessing to improve results.

Comment: Is data normalization as simple as passing the `observationsRdd` through `StandardScaler`?

Comment: That is *one* way of normalizing data. The problem is, you not only want to do something, you want to preprocess the data so it solves *your* problem. Otherwise, you just get "something" out. Do you want "something"?

Comment: FYI, I have pushed an improvement to ELKI Github that no longer requires data normalization by doing a smarter initialization. Since I do not use Spark, don't expect me to do a similar change there.

Comment: Thank you. Normalization yielded better results.